# ConcurrentModificationException although secure removeIF used

Tags: java, list, loops, jpanel

The Exception occurs while trying to repaint a list of Objects after some of them have been removed from a list. The Items are removed via the secure `Collections.removeIf(...)` method. The Exception occurrs within a JPanels `repaint()` chain.

Important methods:

```
public void run() {
    isRunning = true;
    while (isRunning) {
        try {
            tick();
            repaint();
            Thread.sleep(20);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Ticking and repainting the objects is split into different methods, each containing loops.

```
private void tick() {
    for (THead head : heads) {
        head.tick();
    }
    for (TTail tTail : tails) {
        tTail.tick();
    }
    tail.removeIf(o -> !o.isAlive());
}
```

TTails may be removed, if the `alive` flag is no longer set.

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    for (TTail tTail : tails) {
        tTail.paint(g2d);
    }
    for (THead head : heads) {
        head.paint(g2d);
    }
}
```

After the tick, all the objects are repainted. Here is, where the `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs. I dont get why though. Its all running within the same Thread and no nested loops are being used. To remove items i use the `removeIf` method, without altering the objects while removing.

Also THeads and TTails do not inherit from any Swing Super-class, so their respective `paint` methods only use the graphics object to execute a paint operation, without breaking a paint chain.

**EDIT 1:**
I have now synchronized access to the pos Object, which is accessed in both `paint()` and `tick()`.

```
public abstract class TPanelObject {
    private Point pos;
    private Object lock = new Object();

    public Point getPos() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            return pos;
        }
    }

    public void setPos(Point pos) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            this.pos = pos;
        }
    }
}
```

It is the only object manipulated during the operation, except for the graphics object itself.

Maybe i need to let `TPanelObject` inherit from `JComponent` and add the Object to the Panel itself. It might be, that the Exception is caused by access to the Graphics object, as its no longer valid at the time of the repaint?

Comment: Try `TTail tTail : new ArrayList( tails )` to iterate over a copy of the collection and avoid the exception caused by the collection modified while iterating over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repaint/paintComponent etc. run in the event thread¹, your `run()` method and `tick()` methods run in a different thread, so you do have multiple threads accessing the same data.

You need to synchronize the access to `tails` (or otherwise make accessing the shared data safe) unfortunately.

¹ You can of course call them from your threads, but the EDT will be performing paints when requested through `repaint()`.

---

```
private void tick() {
    for (THead head : heads) {
        head.tick();
    }
    for (TTail tTail : tails) {
        tTail.tick();
    }
    synchronized(tails) {
        tail.removeIf(o -> !o.isAlive());
    }
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    synchronized(tails) {
        for (TTail tTail : tails) {
            tTail.paint(g2d);
        }
    }
    for (THead head : heads) {
        head.paint(g2d);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `paint`-method is the only outer access to the tTail objects. Only with `tick()` and `paint()` they perform internal operations. They do not access each other though.

Comment: @TorhanBartel your `tick()` and `paintComponent()` methods run in different threads. If `tick()` removes an element while `paintComponent()` is iterating the collection, you'll get `ConcurrentModifcationException`. Painting is asynchronous, you can't control when it actually happens. Calling `repaint()` just makes a request for repainting.

Comment: @TorhanBartel you should also see from the stacktrace which thread is throwing the exception. I bet you dollars to donuts that it's the AWT Event thread.

Comment: Ok, done that. Check my edit. And yes, it is the AWT Thread :D

Comment: @TorhanBartel You're synching on the wrong thing. You should be syncing access to `tails`. You're inventing all sorts of crazy theories, when I told you what to do. See edit for example code.